# How to get the value of groups in preg_match_all php?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

**Hi, My pattern is:**

```
'<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'\s+/>'
```

**And the string:**

```
<div class="nwstxtpic">
                        <span id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img alt="xxxxx" title="xxxxx" src='xxxxx' />
```

**Well, my php code for finding and getting the value of 4 groups that i have defined in patern is:**

```
$picinfo=preg_match_all('/<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'\s+/>/',$newscontent,$matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo $match;
}
```

I dont know how to get the value of these 4 groups

```
href="(.*)"

alt="(.*)"

title="(.*)"

src=\'(.*)\'
```

Whould you please Help me?
Thank you.

Comment: it may be better to use xml Parsers instead of regular expressions

Comment: @Yazmat Whould you please give me an example? I dont know how can i use xml parser. Does it works as preg_mach to find some pattern? Thank you

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php/3577662#3577662

Answer (score 7, accepted):

preg_match_all() by default returns the result in pattern order, which is not very convenient. Pass the PREG_SET_ORDER flag so that the data is arranged in a more logical way:

```
$newscontent='<span id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img alt="xxxxx" title="xxxxx" src=\'xxxxxbb\' />'; 

$picinfo=preg_match_all('/<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'\s+\/>/',$newscontent,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $href = $match[1];
    $alt = $match[2];
    $title = $match[3];
    $src = $match[4];
    echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. But still not working. Page prints nothing! The code is:<?php
$newscontent='<span id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img alt="xxxxx" title="xxxxx" src=\'xxxxx\' />';

$picinfo=preg_match_all('/<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'\s+/>/',$newscontent,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $href = $match[1];
    $alt = $match[2];
    $title = $match[3];
    $src = $match[4];

echo $title;
}

?>

Comment: You forgot to escape the last slash in your regular expression, that's why.

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry to say that but I am just a beginner!  How can i escape the last slash. Would you please show it in the code? Thank you

Comment: Even I have changed the code by my thought of escaping last slash so:<?php $newscontent='<span id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img alt="xxxxx" title="xxxxx" src=\'xxxxx\' />'; $picinfo=preg_match_all('/<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><‌​a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'‌​\s+\/>/',$newscontent,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER); foreach ($matches as $match) { $href = $match[1]; $alt = $match[2]; $title = $match[3]; $src = $match[4]; echo $title; } ?> But still not working.

Comment: The testing page is: http://usme.ir/news/example.php. I just copied this code in php file but you can see that there is no result.

Comment: The /> part at the end needs to be \/>

Comment: I just changed the code as you said but it is not working. the code:  <?php
 $newscontent='<span id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img alt="xxxxx" title="xxxxx" src=\'xxxxx\' />';
 $picinfo=preg_match_all('/<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><‌​a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'‌​\s+\/>/',$newscontent,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER); 
foreach ($matches as $match) { $href = $match[1]; $alt = $match[2]; $title = $match[3]; $src = $match[4]; echo $title; } 
?> PLEASE HELP ME. Thank you.

Comment: YES, That is working. You are so awesome for helping me solve this mystery. REALLY THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx is correct, as the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) says, by default `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is followed which orders results so that `$matches[0]` is an array of full pattern matches, `$matches[1]` is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So as in your case, $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will contain the href, $matches[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) will contain the alt and so on. Like,

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($matches[0]); $i++ )
     echo "href = {$matches[1][$i]}, alt = {$matches[2][$i]}";
```

`$matches[0]` will contain the full matched strings.

BTW, it is always advisable to use an XML parser, try DOMDocument. [The obligatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Hi,Thanks so much for your response. I have checked it bot still Nothing as value! The code is:<?php
$newscontent='<span id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a href="xxxxx" target="_blank"><img alt="xxxxx" title="xxxxx" src=\'xxxxx\' />';

$picinfo=preg_match_all('/<span\s+id="bodyHolder_newstextDetail_nwstxtPicPane"><a\s+href="(.*)"\s+target="_blank"><img\s+alt="(.*)"\s+title="(.*)"\s+src=\'(.*)\'\s+/>/',$newscontent,$matches);
for($i = 0; $i <= count($matches[0]); $i++ )
     echo "href = {$matches[1][$i]}, alt = {$matches[2][$i]}";

?> Would you please help me? thank you